# Об авторском неологизме «случайно-неслучайно»

Tags: лексика, неологизмы

Как известно, авторские неологизмы придумывают авторы для решения своих художественных задач.  Меня заинтересовал  этот неологизм, который недавно упоминался на форуме, но его хотели  закрыть, а потом он вообще исчез.

Но вот почему, разве он так уж неинтересен?

Готовая дефисная форма для него имеется: ***волей-неволей, как-никак***. И значение вполне понятное: ***случайно или неслучайно***. Кстати, в литературе такие сочетания встречаются, например:

А между тем, **случайно или неслучайно,** с его исчезновением все мои новые друзья словно сгинули. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. (1877-1883)]

Пришел он **случайно или неслучайно** в тот самый Киев  … [Н. С. Лесков. Письма Л. Н. Толстому (1887-1894)]

Я бы предложила такой вариант использования этого слова в речи:  ***Случайно-неслучайно**, но встретиться нам всё-таки пришлось.*

**И вопрос:**  Может ли слово "случайно-неслучайно" заменить сочетание "случайно или неслучайно" и какая форма написания лучше подойдет?

Comment: Я не понимаю, откуда взяться такоиу новообразованию. Волей-неволей - калька, (что интересно - одновременно семантическая и фонетичкеская)  с французского, исходно от латинского  volens и nolens, как-никак имеет определенный смысл, отличный от "как или никак", ибо "никак" не есть прямое отрицания "как", это разве что весьма слабый антоним. Других примеров я просто не знаю.

Comment: В нацкорпусе 68 примеров употребления сочетания "волей или неволей", например: Закрытая веками страна должна будет распахнуть миру свои объятия: волей или неволей. Здесь возможна замена: волей-неволей. Такой же смысл имеет сочетание "хочешь не хочешь": Значит, хочешь не хочешь, а надо возвращаться (533 примера). Поэтому такие конструкции характерны для русского языка.

Comment: И смысл другой - и конструкция другая. "Воленс-нолес" и "Хочешь не хочешь" означают отсутствие возможности человека повлиять на кокое-то событие, необходимость какого-то действия. При чем здесь "случайность"? И почему именно она? А чем утром-вечером хуже? Или мужчина-женщина.

Comment: Случайность тут, разумеется, ни при чем. Этот комментарий по поводу  французской кальки для наречия волей-неволей. Вообще-то это фразеологизм латинского происхождения, в каждом европейском языке он имел свою форму. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tU9ZWg3yEsU
В русском языке варианты "волей-неволей" и "волей или неволей"  явно связаны между собой.  Соответственно, такая схема словообразования   возможна и для других антонимов с приставкой НЕ.  К тому же у меня вопрос, а не ответ. Я всего лишь предполагаю, что форма написания у подобных слов  была бы дефисная, не более того.

Comment: во-первых, я знаю, что исходно - из латинского, об этом написал. Но тем не менее - калька именно с французского, из других языков попасть в русский просто не было шанса.. Во-вторых, коли случайность (о которой вы толкуете в вопросе!) здесь ни при чем, так чего вы вообще вспомнили об этом выражении?

Comment: Я тут еще одно выражение вспомнила - видимо-невидимо.  Тоже дефисное написание антонимов с приставкой НЕ. Это ведь не калька, нет?

Comment: Это не калька, но у этого выражения и смысл не тот, что у всех прочих вами поминаемых. На уровне идиомы. "видимо-невидимо" - это не "видимо или невидимо", это сомсем даже ***очень много***.То есть тут есть некий мотив. И все же, при чем тут "случайно-неслучайно"? Почему вы именно его выбрали кпндидатом на вхождение в язык? А не сказем "Горячо-негорячо", "сладко-несладко" или "зелено-незелено"?

Comment: Это наречие с  определенным смыслом: так или иначе, а результат (или факт) один и тот же.

Comment: *а результат (или факт) один и тот же* - Вы про "хочешь - не хочешь" и "видимо-невидимо"? Да Господь с Вами, что Вы такое говорите-то?. Посмотрите в словарь, у видимо-невидимо только один смысл "очень много". Никакого "результата" там не предполагается. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE

Comment: Я Вас прошу, хватит примеров непонятно чего. Сформулируйте мотив, по которому это сочетание должно занять свое место в языке как самодостаточное выражение. У всех ваших примеров такой мотив есть. Все такие конструкции приобретают дополнительный смысл, не вытекающий из смысла составляющих. Или даже иенняют его

Comment: К сожалению, мне непонятно, о чем мы вообще разговариваем? Я вам сообщила такие факты: 1) В русском языке существует дефисная форма написания наречий, образованных антонимами, в том числе с приставкой НЕ. Они образуются  из словосочетаний с различными союзами (видимо-невидимо от "и видимо, и невидимо", волей-неволей - от "волей или неволей".  2) Смысл неологизма  "случайно-неслучайно" я тоже объяснила.  3) Выбор дефисного написания для него понятен. Извините, но мне к перечисленному здесь нечего добавить, кроме того что  спасибо за ваше внимание к моему вопросу.

Comment: Мне тоже непонятно. Поэтому я и задал конкретный вопрос, какова мотивация для появления в языке этого изобретения. Ответа, увы, не получил.

Comment: А форма «случайно не случайно» не будет приемлемой? Хотя бы из-за лучшей читабельности?

Comment: Вообще-то неплохой вариант, мне нравится. Более художественный, звучит действительно красиво. Ударением в этом случае выделены оба слова. Спасибо. Может быть, вы оформите комментарий как ответ, а то его не видно.